# Setting color by random number asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a method to get a random color:

```
 private System.Drawing.Color GetRandColor()
    {
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        System.Drawing.Color[] colours = 
        {
            System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 
            System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen, 
            System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan,
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon,  
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
        };

        int i = r.Next(0, colours.Length - 1);

        System.Drawing.Color c = colours[i];

        return c; 
    }
```

So what I want to do, is to have this random color passed into my html when the page loads. 
So it will be put in Page_Load somehow:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
              // code to set button color 
    } 

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor=GetRandColor()/>
```

Comment: So, do you want to change your button background color on its click event ?

Comment: Does it mean you want to select any color in random manner from this array?

Comment: No I want to set it in the Page_Load event.

Comment: **Button.BackColor** is used to change the background color of a button.

Comment: OK, but what if the button is in a DIV. so I want to randomly set the color of a html element background, not an asp.net control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background color of button in C# code itself. Please check the method.

```
private void GetRandColor()
    {
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        System.Drawing.Color[] colours = 
        {
            System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 
            System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen, 
            System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan,
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon,  
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
        };

        int i = r.Next(0, colours.Length - 1);

        System.Drawing.Color c = colours[i];

        Button1.BackColor = c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your method as common one

```
private void GetRandColor(object sender)
{
    Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    System.Drawing.Color[] colours = 
    {
        System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 
        System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen, 
        System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan,
        System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon,  
        System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue
    };

    int i = r.Next(0, colours.Length - 1);

    System.Drawing.Color c = colours[i];

    Button btn = (Button)sender; 
    btn.BackColor = c;
}
```